# mysql: How can list 2 different condition, ordering, and limit requirements from one table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

There is a table of men and women.
The table has the field, sex which has the values, men or women.

```
TABEL-A

ID SEX    GRADE-A   GRADE=B
1  men      2          4     
2  women    4          5
3  women    6          1
4  men      1          3
5  men      3          6
6  men      5          2
```

I want to sort the table as below;

First, list only 2 from men ordering by GRADE-A DESC.

Second, list all rest from both men and woman ordering by GRADE-B DESC

Expected Output;

```
ID SEX    GRADE-A   GRADE=B
6  men      5          2     
5  men      3          6
2  women    4          5
1  men      2          4
4  men      1          3     
3  women    6          1
```

Because these 2 conditions have different ordering requirement so I could not use UNION.
Also UNION is slow.

Here is my failed query, part 1

```
select distinct t.*
(
(
select *
from TABLE-A a
where a.sex = 'men'
order by a.GRADE-A DESC
LIMIT 2
)
UNION ALL
(
select *
from TABLE-A a
order by a.GRADE-B DESC
)
) t
```

Also I tried "case when" logic, but cannot limit 2 men at first,

Here is my failed query, part 2

```
select *
from TABLE-A a
order by 
case when a.sex = 'men' then a.GRADE-A end DESC, a.GRADE-B DESC
```

Could anyone support to make proper query for this?

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM `TABLE-A` a
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT m2.ID
    FROM `TABLE-A` m2
    WHERE m2.sex = 'men'
    ORDER BY m2.`GRADE-A` DESC
    LIMIT 2
  ) m2 ON m2.ID = a.ID
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN m2.ID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
  CASE WHEN m2.ID IS NULL THEN a.`GRADE-B` ELSE a.`GRADE-A` END DESC
```

Test it on [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81592/9)

*Explanation:*

To understand how `ORDER BY` works, see at this table - here are all `TABLE-A` data plus values of some expressions in query (**CASE1** refers to first CASE expression, **CASE2** - to second):

```
ID SEX    GRADE-A   GRADE=B  m2.ID   CASE1  CASE2
1  men      2          4     NULL      1      4
2  women    4          5     NULL      1      5
3  women    6          1     NULL      1      1
4  men      1          3     NULL      1      3
5  men      3          6     5         0      3
6  men      5          2     6         0      5
```

`ORDER BY` sorts rows by **CASE1** values (in ascending order) and then by **CASE2** (in descending). So after sort we have what is expected:

```
ID SEX    GRADE-A   GRADE=B  m2.ID   CASE1  CASE2
6  men      5          2     6         0      5
5  men      3          6     5         0      3
2  women    4          5     NULL      1      5
1  men      2          4     NULL      1      4
4  men      1          3     NULL      1      3
3  women    6          1     NULL      1      1
```

More info about [**Sorting Rows**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for the query and testing it in advance. I'm still try it on my program, but this query seems to work great. I just wonder why ` order by case when XX is null then 1 else 0`  separate NULL records and others.

Comment: @user3775389 added explanation how `ORDER BY` works in this query

Comment: I totally understood how the `ORDER BY` works thanks to your explanation. This is very important knowledge for me.

Comment: Thanks to @Rimas I could made query which accomplish my requirement, but It is a bit slow maybe because of left join sub-query to list limited number of users at first. I add another, more specific question for people understand detail in my issue; [How to get this query faster by eliminating “using temporally; using filesort”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26335149/mysql-how-to-get-this-query-faster-by-eliminating-using-temporally-using-file)

Comment: @user3775389 I think query is slow because there are `CASE` statements in `ORDER BY`. I don't think what `LEFT JOIN` slows down as it return only 2 rows. So my suggestion is to use two separate queries with simple `ORDER BY` expressions and combine results in the program. Also create two additional indexes, see example on SQL Fidle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56f95/1

Comment: two separate queries actually be executed faster than merged version. I am working on my program by using separated queries, but I wish I could have one simple query for the simplicity of the program.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct t.*
(
(
select *
from TABLE-A a
where a.sex = 'men'
order by a.GRADE-A DESC
LIMIT 2
)
UNION ALL
(
select *
from TABLE-A a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   (select *
    from TABLE-A a
    where a.sex = 'men'
    order by a.GRADE-A DESC
    LIMIT 2) table1
ON a.ID = table1.ID 
order by a.GRADE-B DESC
)
) t
```

this will give you the first query result and add the missing rows in the order you want them

Comment: Thank you for your advise, but "Except" syntax does not work on my MYSQL environment.

Comment: not sure if this is going to work, but that is the logic. i have nothing to try it on my computer :/

Comment: Thank you for your modification, but sub-table name, "table1" can not be used in this query. The following sample query works, but if I add table1 for 1st query, it goes error; `select distinct t.* from ( ( select * from TABLE-A a where a.sex = 'men' order by a.GRADE-A DESC LIMIT 2 ) /*table1*/ UNION ALL ( select * from TABLE-A a /*LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 ON a2.ID = a1.ID*/ order by a.GRADE-B DESC ) ) t`

Comment: Sorry for my confusing you, but I just wanted to tell that The query you posted didn't work because of adding the table name, table1.